# Why did the Trojans accept Paris back?

Tags: greek, trojan-war

I just learned that Paris was exposed as a baby (left outside to die).

How did he survive? If he was exposed, why did the Trojans accept him back as their prince?

Answer (score -2):

Paris survived with Agelais help on the Gargarus by the mountain Ida. He returned to Troy when Trojans prepared games with bulls, and won.

Source-Robert Graves,The Greek myths,chapter 159.,Paris and Helena.

Comment: A little more elaboration would make this answer better.

Comment: Trojan games with bulls instruct to the Minoian  games with the bulls,also talks about  migration from Crete to Troy.The remain of this cult I found in IstrianTroy - Motovun ,in the local game named-"throwing the horn."-you motivated me, Semaphore.